# Build error: Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12 while building android studio's basic app

Tags: android-studio, junit, junit4, android-studio-2.2

I'm very new to android app development. Trying to write a basic android mobile app using android studio2.2.3. DIdn't add of my code but just have the default code that was created by the android studio:

```
package com.example.nam.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;   
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to compile the app but getting the below error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Connect to repo1.maven.org:80 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:80 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Can anyone kindly help me understand the issue here. Please kindly request provide some details as i'm very new to android studio &it's usage & android app development.

Comment: You have a connectivity issue. Check your internet connection and try again

Comment: MY internet connection is fine, i verified again. Has it some thing to do with proxy settings. I selected auto-proxy.

Comment: I also have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097056/unable-to-build-gradle-and-create-java-class