# Unable to build gradle and create java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

Any project in my android studio fails to build.The error message is as follows-

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'.
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Moreover i'm unable to make a new java class in android studio by File->new->Java class as no such option is available. I found some answers saying right click on java folder then clicking Mark Directory as -> SOurce root, even this option is not there . Moreover, for resolving the gradle issue, i found some answers saying click File->Invalidate Caches/Restart and delete the .gradle file in home directory then update android studio, i did accordingly but still nothing works.
build.gradle contents are-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.iitmandi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Contents of gradle-wrapper.properties are-

```
#Tue Mar 28 20:10:53 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Build.grale-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

on doing Build->Clean project this error message was shown-

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out
```

I even uninstalled Android-Studio 2.3 and installed 2.2.2 instead but still the problem persists

Comment: Can you post your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file located in `gradle` directory?

Comment: What is that `Show Log` thing? Command? Hyperlink? Can you post the log that will contain more details of the error?

Comment: Everything looks ok to me. Not sure what is the main cause, But I would suggest you try deleting the current settings of Studio and restart your PC. It should work.

Comment: when i tried to build project the building process was taking a lot of time so i cancelled it and the message displayed was- Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto do you mean reinstall this version of android studio

Comment: @MattClark i've attched the error meassage , please have a look

Comment: Ummm... Go to *USER%/Masquerade/ , there you'll find a directory named as .AndroidStudio2.3, delete this directory and restart your PC and try opening AS again

Comment: Join this chat room if the issue persist: [Java and Android Era](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era)

Comment: Got the sol!!  I set the https proxy wrong , on setting it right again everything works just fine

Answer (score -1):

the code in JUnit library is referenced in the project but there is no related JUnit dependent library yet...you either have to delete the referencing line(s) of code in the gradle or install the JUnit library.For more info https://debugah.com/failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12-how-to-solve-11544/